# Refresh list on Events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

In my application i have listbox that updated from database.

The changes that can be [Buttons] (OnClick events)

- Insert new row/rows.
- Delete row/rows.
- Edit Row.
- Refresh the list.

i have a function to do the refresh:

```
public void DBListBoxRefresh()
{
   dbListBox.DataSource = dbPersonList;
}
```

How can i made Event That on every event of that type will refresh the listbox automatically. or other ideas how can i make it instead of invoking the function from every event

Comment: Just call `DBListBoxRefresh();` in `MainForm_Load` and `btnNew_Click`. You even don't need a delegate. What's the problem?

Comment: OK, but what's the usage of the delegate?  You want to call a method. Call it. For example you can write: `btnNew.Click += (obj,arg)=>DBListBoxRefresh();` and `this.Load += (obj,arg)=>DBListBoxRefresh();`.

Comment: i will make list in the app with all the events i need it to run and when i will need to delete or add one it all will be in one place

Comment: Probably you have a good idea in your mind, but unfortunately I can't understand what you mean. The only thing that I can understand from your question at the moment is you want to call a single method in 2 different event handlers and so the answer is what I said in comments.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Just to understand, is that more or less what I suggested in answer but with C#6 syntax? First time seeing that syntax tbh.

Comment: @uteist, No, that has nothing to do wih C# 6.0. He is using [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx), that are kind of anonymous methods in this case, while you are using named methods. But they are quite the same, except that he cannot unsubscribe from lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go with `+=` for specific event.

For example:

```
btnMyButton.Click += CustomEventForMyButton;

private void CustomEventForMyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: btnMyButton.Click ?

Comment: @LeonBarkan Yeah, just as an example. I just wanted to show that you can use `+=` operator for adding another event to whatever control that you want to use. For your case, it would be `btnNew` and you should obviously call your `RefreshDBListBox` within the `CustomEventForMyButton` method, instead of throwing NotImplementedException.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `RefreshDBListBox rdbl = DBListBoxRefresh;`

Comment: I think i didn't explained myself correct, i will add it to the question